# Example of Using getInsight() api from Rfacebook in R

Tags: r, facebook-graph-api

Examples on how to use getInsight() and what kind of parameters to pass in the api from Rfacebook package in R.
Also what is the return type of the above API, and how to pass multiple values for "metric" argument in the api and again what will be the return type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a temporary token from Facebook.
Go to developers.facebook.com -> Tools & Support -> Graph API Explorer -> Get Token -> Get User Access Token.

Then check box under Select Permissions -> Other -> read_insights.
Now you can copy your token:

```
token <- "EAACE*****************ZDZD" #Copy your token
# take your page id from http://findmyfbid.com/
page_id <- "123456" # Copy your page id (only owner or admin of page)
# Combine your metrics
multipleMetrics <- c('page_fans','page_fans_country','page_impressions')
```

Now you can use `getInsights()` function like a following query:

```
insights <- getInsights(object_id = page_id, token = token, metric = multipleMetrics, period = 'lifetime')
```